# How to use multi -package java application in my web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, web, build, maven-3

The doubt is regarding the compiling and building war for the tomcat.
I have the standalone maven application which has multiple packages(not multi module - one pom for entire application) with multiple Java classes. 
Below is my POM for the java app:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>projectCore</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectCore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
// dependencies
</project>
```

I have another maven web application where the java application classes are referred.

Below is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>projectWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectWeb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
//dependencies
<project>
```

Whenever I do a build of the Java application, it deletes the target directory in my java app and creates a pom file in .m2 directory(which is same pom in the java app named as artifactId-version.pom), what I don't understand is that how should I use the java app containing classes to be available in web app, and that web app to be finally deployed in apache tomcat 7.

**EDIT** Basically, how to do i compile my java app with pom packaging to be used in my web app? 
can I use deployment Assembly available in eclipse ?

Eclipse : mars2 
java version 7

Comment: As you're new to Maven tool, you should first read its documentation ([http://maven.apache.org/guides/]). It explains what is Maven, its syntax, how to use it. Then if you face a problem, you should post a question on SO.

Comment: @mark42inbound : hey mark, i have read the documentation, i have the project changes for deployment for which i did not find any way to go about in my specific case mentioned above. Well , my concern is how to i use pom file generated in .m2 directory by clean compile package command of my java application in my web application.